# How should we implement @DELETE method?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, http-delete

https://..../v1/trails/245

@DELETE("v1/trails/")

Comment: Please add more details in your question.

Comment: I want to add 245 to the end of /v1/trails/

Comment: Check my answer, Should work for you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the id as variable , Code like that

```
  @DELETE("v1/trails/{id}")
  Call<Response> delete(@Path("id") int id);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this answer for the address  v1/trails/id?245

Comment: while for this address I want    v1/trails/245

Comment: Please explain your problem with more information. Otherwise it's difficult to address your problem. Before posting any problem search over the google and add your so far findings.